# error: no match for ‘operator==’ In Boost Graph and OMPL

Tags: c++, boost, operator-overloading, operators, dijkstra

I am trying to use Boost Dijkstra as shown in [here](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Boost/BGL/DijkstraComputePath).
I am using OMPL library and the boost graph declaration can be found [here](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/PlannerDataGraph_8h_source.html).
declaration of `ob::Cost` can be found [here](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/Cost_8h_source.html).
Write the below code.
When I compile it say this error:

```cpp
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const ompl::base::Cost’ and ‘const ompl::base::Cost’)
```

How I can solve it?

```cpp
typedef ob::Cost  Weight;
typedef ob::PlannerData::Graph Graph;
typedef ob::PlannerData::Graph::Vertex Vertex;

typedef boost::property_map < Graph, boost::vertex_index_t >::type IndexMap;

typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Vertex*, IndexMap, Vertex, Vertex& > PredecessorMap;
typedef boost::iterator_property_map < Weight*, IndexMap, Weight, Weight& > DistanceMap;

std::vector<Vertex> predecessors(boost::num_vertices(graph)); // To store parents
std::vector<Weight> distances(boost::num_vertices(graph)); // To store distances
IndexMap indexMap = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, graph);
PredecessorMap predecessorMap(&predecessors[0], indexMap);
DistanceMap distanceMap(&distances[0], indexMap);

Vertex v0 = data->getStartIndex(0);

//Compute shortest paths from v0 to all vertices, and store the output in predecessors and distances
//boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, v0, boost::predecessor_map(predecessorMap).distance_map(distanceMap));
//This is exactly the same as the above line - it is the idea of "named parameters" - you can pass the
//prdecessor map and the distance map in any order.
boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(graph, v0, boost::distance_map(distanceMap).predecessor_map(predecessorMap));
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Also `Cost` has no `operator==`, just as the error indicates.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The line of the `boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths`